# How to delete this Server Intelligence Agent (SIA) server

Tags: content-management-system, business-objects

Hi I can't delete the below server. the middle row, how can I delete it?  Obviously I already tried to use the delete 'X' on the top of the CCM box that you are supposed to use:

[image]

When I try to delete it, I see this:

> Failed to locate a node with name BIAPPPROD11 in the CMS. Verify your CMS connection information.
>
> [image]

Is there some place in the registry I can delete it?  Is there a place in the CMS?  I realize I can blow up everything and do it again but that's not an option right now, so please do not give that as my option.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deleted it form Windows services

Answer (score 1):

**`*steps for deleting SIA from CCM`***

1. Launch Central Configuration manager (CCM).
2. Stop the Server Intelligence Agent (SIA) to be deleted.
3. Go to Windows Start > Run and type in "services. MSc" without the quotes and press Enter key.
4. In the Services applet, find the SIA service to be deleted say Server Intelligent Agent (BI40).
5. Go to Properties of Server Intelligent Agent (BI40).
6. Under the General tab, copy the Service name BOEXI40SIABI40 to the clipboard.
7. Open command prompt and run following command:sc delete BOEXI40SIABI40
8. Navigate to "Install Directory\Program Files (x86)\SAP Business Objects\SAP Business Objects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64" directory and delete the following files for Server Intelligent Agent (BI40). 
   _boe_BI40.bootstrap 
   _boe_BI40.bootstrap.backup 
   _boe_BI40.bootstrap.original 
   _boe_BI40.dbinfo

(NOTE- make sure that you are having more then 1 SIA else the server gets shutdown. And be sure which SIA files you are deleteing when you are going to path to win 64 directory.)
Vikram